# Default value of the space between rows in a tabular environment

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, line-spacing

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular}{l}
    \textbf{« Ah ! comme la neige a neigé !} \\
    \textbf{Ma vitre est un jardin de givre.} \\
    \textbf{Ah ! comme la neige a neigé !} \\
    \textbf{Qu'est-ce que le spasme de vivre} \\
    \textbf{À la douleur que j'ai, que j'ai ! [...] »} \\
    Émile Nelligan
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

I want to double the space between the last rows, so that the name of the poet be disjoint from the poem. I know I can add an argument in brackets to the `\\` to put more vertical space, but I don't know what is the exact value of the space between rows in a `\tabular` environment. All I've found is that it has default value 1 when trying to renew the command `\arraystretch` in the preamble. Since 1 is dimensionless, this tells me absolutely nothing about the real value.

Comment: Use an empty line `\\~\\ Émile Nelligan`

Comment: Have you considered the verse package?

Comment: @pablos No, I haven't. But thanks for letting me know it exists.

Comment: @Amateur you can find how to typeset poetry here http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/verse/verse.pdf

Comment: The `\vspace*{\fill}` at the beginning of your code let mea think perhaps you want to typeset epigraphs. If this is indeed the case, there *is*  an `epigraph` package. Otherwise, less  known than `verse` is the `gmverse` package that's dedicated to typesetting verses too long to fit on one line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, in an `array` or `tabular` environment, line spacing is done by placing a strut in every row of height and depth given by `\arraystretch` times the height and depth of the strut produced by an ordinary `\strut` commmand. Thus, you can get the desired value (under normal circumstances) with something like

```
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\arraystretch\ht\strutbox+\arraystretch\dp\strutbox\relax}
```

So you could do:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\arraystretch\ht\strutbox+\arraystretch\dp\strutbox\relax}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular}{l}
    \textbf{« Ah ! comme la neige a neigé !} \\
    \textbf{Ma vitre est un jardin de givre.} \\
    \textbf{Ah ! comme la neige a neigé !} \\
    \textbf{Qu'est-ce que le spasme de vivre} \\
    \textbf{À la douleur que j'ai, que j'ai ! [...] »} \\[\mylen]
    Émile Nelligan
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

The exact same result would be obtained with an empty additional row:

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
    \textbf{« Ah ! comme la neige a neigé !} \\
    \textbf{Ma vitre est un jardin de givre.} \\
    \textbf{Ah ! comme la neige a neigé !} \\
    \textbf{Qu'est-ce que le spasme de vivre} \\
    \textbf{À la douleur que j'ai, que j'ai ! [...] »} \\
    \\
    Émile Nelligan
\end{tabular}
```

However, as has been noticed in comments, to typeset poetry instead of using a `tabular` you could use the standard `verse` environment or the features provided by a number of dedicated packages such as:

- [`verse`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/verse).
- [`gmverse`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gmverse).

In CTAN, under [`Poetry and Drama`](http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/bytopic.html#literature) you'll find a list of other related packages.

In case you are interested in epigraphs, the [`epigraph`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epigraph) package could be of interest for standard classes; `memoir` and the KOMA classes offer their own epigraph mechanisms.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from reminding about the `verse` environment (and the package with the same name that provides some enhancements), I want to suggest using a special environment for this: the advantage is greater flexibility.

In the example I show that by just modifying the definition of `\poet` you get a different effect without acting on all poems.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     % <---- Don't forget this with French!
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\newenvironment{poetry}[1][]
 {#1\begin{tabular}{l}}
 {\end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\poet}[1]{\noalign{\vspace{.5\normalbaselineskip}}\normalfont#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{poetry}[\bfseries]
« Ah ! comme la neige a neigé ! \\
Ma vitre est un jardin de givre. \\
Ah ! comme la neige a neigé ! \\
Qu'est-ce que le spasme de vivre \\
À la douleur que j'ai, que j'ai ! [...] » \\
\poet{Émile Nelligan}
\end{poetry}

\bigskip

\begin{poetry}[\itshape]
« Ah ! comme la neige a neigé ! \\
Ma vitre est un jardin de givre. \\
Ah ! comme la neige a neigé ! \\
Qu'est-ce que le spasme de vivre \\
À la douleur que j'ai, que j'ai ! [...] » \\
\poet{Émile Nelligan}
\end{poetry}

\bigskip

% this is how \poet could be defined in the preamble
\renewcommand{\poet}[1]{%
  \noalign{\vspace{.5\normalbaselineskip}}%
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{\normalfont\scshape#1}%
}

\begin{poetry}
« Ah ! comme la neige a neigé ! \\
Ma vitre est un jardin de givre. \\
Ah ! comme la neige a neigé ! \\
Qu'est-ce que le spasme de vivre \\
À la douleur que j'ai, que j'ai ! [...] » \\
\poet{Émile Nelligan}
\end{poetry}

\end{document}
```

[image]